# Manipulate CSS of class that is to be added after DOM load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a news scroller which is created by appending `li`s from an array to a `ul` element. I am making it scroll via the following function:

```
$newsItem = $('.news-item');

function newsScroll() {
  $newsItem.eq(currentNewsItem).fadeIn(1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $newsItem.eq(currentNewsItem).addClass('move-left');
  }, 2000);
}
```

It adds `.move-left` class to `li` where `.move-left` has CSS rules:

```
.move-left {
  -webkit-transition: 5s;
  -moz-transition: 5s;
  -ms-transition: 5s;
  -o-transition: 5s;
  transition: 5s;
  left: -400px;
}
```

The problem is that all the news items are not the same length; some of them exceed the 400px. Thus moving them 400px left, doesn't scroll them out of the display of the scroller.

So I have used the following code to determine the width of the longest of these elements, but I am unsure how to affix this to the class `.move-left`, or how to alter a class that is not a part of the DOM.

```
var moveLeftAmt = Math.max.apply(null, $('ul#newsScroller li').map(function() {
  return $(this).outerWidth(true);
}).get());
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could write the updated style rule to a `<style>` block in the header. You can add an id to the inline style block to make it easier to target, then just do `$('styleID').html('{ // new style rules }');` and write your dynamic styles that way.

Comment: Can you try using `transform: translateX(-100%)` instead of `left`? this should pull the element 100% of its own width, to the left

Comment: The problem with using `transform` in that way is that every element scrolls over the same duration, so smaller elements (ones with a significantly smaller width) will scroll much slower than larger elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially based on the suggestion of @HimanshuUpadhyay, I altered the style of the body tag via the `attr` function, including a CSS `var` like so:

```
$('body').attr('style',"--amtLeft:"+moveLeftAmt);
```

which I then referenced in the stylesheet:

```
.move-left {
  -webkit-transition: 5s;
  -moz-transition: 5s;
  -ms-transition: 5s;
  -o-transition: 5s;
  transition: 5s;
  left: var(--amtLeft) !important;
}
```

Works like a charm!

I should note that

```
var moveLeftAmt = Math.max.apply(null, $('ul#newsScroller li').map(function() {
  return $(this).outerWidth(true);
}).get());
```

simply returns a number, so to use it in this way I had to declare another variable that adds the `"px"` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can do like this:

```
var moveLeftAmt = Math.max.apply(null, $('ul#newsScroller li').map(function() {
return $(this).outerWidth(true);
}).get());
```

So with above code you will get the highest width in `moveLeftAmt`and then apply it to the element as an inline css using the following code:

```
$newsItem.eq(currentNewsItem).css('left',moveLeftAmt);
```

OR

```
$newsItem.eq(currentNewsItem).attribute('style',"left:"+moveLeftAmt+"px;");  // Appended `px` after the variable.
```

Comment: This almost works! The CSS transition doesn't work, however. I tried this an the effect still did not apply: `$newsItem.eq(currentNewsItem).attr('style',"left:"+moveLeft+";-webkit-transition:5s;transition:5s");` The element simply disappeared.

Comment: So when you add class with this line `setTimeout(function() {
    $newsItem.eq(currentNewsItem).addClass('move-left');
  }, 2000);` it does not show transition effect?

Comment: Correct. It did not.

Comment: @codeEnthusiast, please check my updated answer. I appended `px` after the JS variable. I missed that in my answer initially.